# Problema al agregar clase con ng-class en AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Tengo la siguiente situación, 4 botones con diferentes rutas de vehículos, cuando le doy **click** a un **botón** se agrega una clase `active` y muestra el contenido que pertenece a esa ruta y adicional se agrega una clase bootstrap `col-md-6` a la palabra **contenido**.
**¿Cual es el problema?**
 Que cuando se le da `click` a varios botones de rutas para activarlos la palabra **contenido** tiene un comportamiento diferente a lo esperado, se espera que si hay botones activos que la palabra **contenido** permanezca con la clase bootstrap `col-md-6` y si no hay botones activos que permanezca con la clase bootstrap `col-md-12`.
 Tengo el siguiente código:
**PD: ver en pantalla completa para ver el comportamiento, que sugieren?**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>Prueba</title>

        <!-- CDN Bootstrap 4 -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .active {
                background-color: red !important;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{'active': showRutaBuses}" ng-click="toggleRutas('buses')">
                        Ruta buses
                    </button>
                    
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{'active': showRutaBicicletas}" ng-click="toggleRutas('bicicletas')">
                        Ruta de bicicletas
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{'active': showRutaMotos}" ng-click="toggleRutas('motos')">
                        Ruta de Motos
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{'active': showRutaCarros}" ng-click="toggleRutas('carros')">
                        Ruta de carros
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div ng-if="showRutaBuses">
                        <h1>Rutas de buses</h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Bus 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Bus 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Bus 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="showRutaBicicletas">
                        <h1>Ruta de Bicicletas</h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Bicileta 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Bicileta 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Bicileta 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="showRutaMotos">
                        <h1>Ruta de Moto</h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Moto 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Moto 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Moto 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="showRutaCarros">
                        <h1>Ruta de Carros</h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Carro 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Carro 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Carro 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div ng-class="{'col-md-6': partContent, 'col-md-12': !partContent }">
                    <h1 class="text-danger">Contenido</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.showRutaBuses = false;
                $scope.showRutaBicicletas = false;
                $scope.showRutaMotos = false;
                $scope.showRutaCarros = false;
                $scope.partContent = false;

                $scope.toggleRutas = function(typeRuoute) {
                    if (typeRuoute == 'buses') {
                        $scope.showRutaBuses = !$scope.showRutaBuses;
                        $scope.partContent = !$scope.partContent;
                    }

                    if (typeRuoute == 'bicicletas') {
                        $scope.showRutaBicicletas = !$scope.showRutaBicicletas;
                        $scope.partContent = !$scope.partContent;
                    }

                    if (typeRuoute == 'motos') {
                        $scope.showRutaMotos = !$scope.showRutaMotos;
                        $scope.partContent = !$scope.partContent;
                    }

                    if (typeRuoute == 'carros') {
                        $scope.showRutaCarros = !$scope.showRutaCarros;
                        $scope.partContent = !$scope.partContent;
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código no te funciona debido a que al dar clic a un botón y cambiar el valor de `$scope.partContent` no estás teniendo en cuenta si los otros botones están activos o no, por lo cual debes preguntar en cada clic si por lo menos alguno de los 4 botones está activo y de ser así mantener `$scope.partContent` como `true`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>Prueba</title>

        <!-- CDN Bootstrap 4 -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .active {
                background-color: red !important;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{'active': showRutaBuses}" ng-click="toggleRutas('buses')">
                        Ruta buses
                    </button>
                    
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{'active': showRutaBicicletas}" ng-click="toggleRutas('bicicletas')">
                        Ruta de bicicletas
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{'active': showRutaMotos}" ng-click="toggleRutas('motos')">
                        Ruta de Motos
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-class="{'active': showRutaCarros}" ng-click="toggleRutas('carros')">
                        Ruta de carros
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div ng-if="showRutaBuses">
                        <h1>Rutas de buses</h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Bus 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Bus 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Bus 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="showRutaBicicletas">
                        <h1>Ruta de Bicicletas</h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Bicileta 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Bicileta 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Bicileta 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="showRutaMotos">
                        <h1>Ruta de Moto</h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Moto 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Moto 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Moto 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="showRutaCarros">
                        <h1>Ruta de Carros</h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Carro 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Carro 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Carro 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div ng-class="{'col-md-6': partContent, 'col-md-12': !partContent }">
                    <h1 class="text-danger">Contenido</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.showRutaBuses = false;
                $scope.showRutaBicicletas = false;
                $scope.showRutaMotos = false;
                $scope.showRutaCarros = false;
                $scope.partContent = false;

                $scope.toggleRutas = function(typeRuoute) {
                    if (typeRuoute == 'buses') {
                        $scope.showRutaBuses = !$scope.showRutaBuses;
                    }

                    if (typeRuoute == 'bicicletas') {
                        $scope.showRutaBicicletas = !$scope.showRutaBicicletas;
                    }

                    if (typeRuoute == 'motos') {
                        $scope.showRutaMotos = !$scope.showRutaMotos;
                    }

                    if (typeRuoute == 'carros') {
                        $scope.showRutaCarros = !$scope.showRutaCarros;
                    }

                    if ($scope.showRutaBuses || $scope.showRutaBicicletas || $scope.showRutaMotos || $scope.showRutaCarros) {
                        $scope.partContent = true;
                    }else{
                        $scope.partContent = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```